# Downloaded, burned to DVD - rebooted but when I choose CD to boot it just goes back to windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, live-usb, dvd, windows-xp

I've used Ubuntu in past, but it was set up through work, and would only boot on my Ram drive so nothing would save.

So I am familiar with booting up using F12 at start and choosing either boot by DVD (cd-rom) or by USB (and used the same usb stick i had from company I no longer work with but reformated it so I could put the ISO onto it.  either way neither effort work.
Always reverts back to windows start up as if I had no boot disk in at all.  Windows XP  is getting really buggy  and I refuse to pay them for newer system that wont run on my older computer. I am on very limited budget (disability) but hoping to keep my computer running for day to day use.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can provide.

Comment: Which tool you are using to make your usb bootable?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you might be just copying a bootable disk ISO to a USB. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're just copying the ISO file to a DVD or USB.  As you're currently running XP, just install [ImgBurn](http://download.imgburn.com/SetupImgBurn_2.5.8.0.exe), open the ISO file in there and then burn it and boot with that.

Alternatively, if you want to use the USB use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.net/download-unetbootin/) (it has a Windows version) and use that to put the ISO file on there.

**Why?**  An ISO file is an image that *contains* the files you need to run (like a ZIP file)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as your and my reputation will go up...